# Embedding cartopy maps in subplots using the inset_axes method

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, python-xarray, cartopy

I have created multiple cross sections of the ocean at specific longitudes, I would like to include a map that shows the location of each cross section, inside the subplot of each of the cross sections.

Here is my code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.path as mpath
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import xarray as xr
import cartopy
import cartopy.crs as ccrs

num_plots = len(range(0, 360, 20))
cols = 2  # Number of columns in the subplot grid
rows = (num_plots + cols - 1) // cols  # Calculate the number of rows

fig, axs = plt.subplots(rows, cols, figsize=(20, 40))

for idx, ax, in zip(range(0, 360, 20), axs.flat):
    im = mydataselection.plot(cmap='plasma', vmin=-2, vmax=8, ax=ax)
    ax.invert_yaxis()
    ax.set_title(f"titlestring")
    ax.set_xticks(xtickvalues)
    ax.set_xticklabels(np.round(xticklabelvalues,1))
    ax.set_xlabel('Longitude [°N]')

    axins = ax.inset_axes([0.1, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3], projection=SouthPolarStereo())
    axins.set_extent([-180, 180, -90, -50], ccrs.PlateCarree())
    axins.add_feature(cartopy.feature.LAND, edgecolor='black', facecolor='gray')
    axins.add_feature(cartopy.feature.OCEAN)
    axins.gridlines()

    # Make circular inset map
    circle = PathPatch(Path.circle((0.5, 0.5), radius=0.5), transform=axins.transAxes, facecolor='none',  edgecolor='black')
    axins.add_patch(circle)


# Hide any remaining empty subplots
for ax in axs.flat[num_plots:]:
    ax.axis('off')

plt.tight_layout()
plt.subplots_adjust(top=0.9)
plt.show()
```

My code works without the 'axins' parts. With it I get a 'NameError: name 'SouthPolarStereo' is not defined'. Is this some conflict between cartopy and inset_axes or is this something else? And how could I make this work properly?

I have tried to use other projections provided in the inset_axes documentation, however, it still gives an error, 'keyError 'geo'' in this case.

Comment: It's a general Python error meaning that the object you refer to doesn't exist in the namespace. In other words, where does this `SouthPolarStereo` comes from, it has to be defined somewhere or else you get the error. For this specific case it looks you should simply use `ccrs.SouthPolarStereo()` instead?